# pointer to read data into an array of structs c++

Tags: c++

I have a text file that looks like:

```
Azrin, Neil
2.3  6.0  5.0  6.7  7.8  5.6  8.9  7.6
Babbage, Charles
2.3  5.6  6.5  7.6  8.7  7.8  5.4  4.5
```

It continues for 24 different names. The first name is on line one and the numbers are on the second line in the file. The first number is the difficulty level of the dive and the follow 7 numbers are the scores given by 7 different judges.

I have been able to read in the divers name and difficulty level but it will not read in the scores that follow the difficulty level.

I have tried just about everything I can think of to get it to work correctly, can anyone please help out?

My code so far to read the data into the struct looks like this

```
const int NUM_NAMES = 24;
const int NUM_SCORES = 7;
const int NUM_ROUNDS = 2;


typedef double scoreTable[NUM_ROUNDS] [NUM_SCORES];
typedef double difficultyList[NUM_ROUNDS];

struct diveInfo
{
string diversName;
double totalScore;
double diveTotal;
difficultyList diff;
scoreTable scores;

};


typedef diveInfo diverList[NUM_NAMES];


int main()
{
diveInfo record;
diveInfo * ptr;
ptr = &record;
int lcv;

ifstream inFile;
inFile.open ("diveData.txt");

if (!inFile)
{
    cout << "ERROR: File could not be opened" << endl << endl;

    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}


for (lcv = 0; lcv < NUM_NAMES; lcv++)

getline(inFile, ptr[lcv].diversName);

delete ptr;
ptr = new diveInfo;

inFile >> *ptr[lcv].diff;

delete ptr;
ptr = new diveInfo[NUM_SCORES];

inFile >> *ptr[lcv].scores;   // here is the problem 

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: scores is a two dimensional array. *ptr[lcv].scores is not accessing what you think it is. It does not look like your data file has 14 scores for each diver, so why are there two rounds of seven in the scores array? Also do you mean to delete the data after you read it from the file? When you type delete ptr you no longer have access to that data you just read.

Comment: you have already de-referenced ptr when you wrote ptr[lcv] so you dont have to use *

Comment: Please improve ur coding style. Lot of errors are there and the coding style looks horrible :(

Answer (score 4):

Your code is horribly confused. I guess it started out simple but when that didn't work it got more and more complicated. But this is quite easy, you don't need anything complicated. The first thing is that you don't need *pointers* and you don't need *new*.

Let's start at the beginning, your structs are wrong, and you cannot get anywhere until you get those right. Think about your data, you have one name, one difficulty score, and seven judges scores. Put that in a struct

```
struct DiveInfo
{
    string diversName;
    double diff;
    double scores[7];
};
```

Now we have 24 different dives, so we need an array of 24 DiveInfo structs

```
DiveInfo diveList[24];
```

Now we can start to do some reading, remember no *pointers* and no *new*. This is simple not complicated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i)
{
    getline(inFile, diveList[i].diversName);
    inFile >> diveList[i].diff;
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
        inFile >> diveList[i].score[j];
    string garbage;
    getline(inFile, garbage); // move to next line, ready to read next name
}
```

See? Each time round the loop we read a single DiveInfo (two lines in your file). Each DiveInfo is a name followed by the difficulty score, followed by the 7 judges scores. The only slightly complicated thing is the `getline(..., garbage);` bit at the end. That is necessary to move the input onto the next line when you have read the last score.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
 typedef double scoreTable[NUM_ROUNDS] [NUM_SCORES];
```

to

```
 typedef double scoreTable[NUM_SCORES];
```

You are not using the second dimension of the array in your program and the data file does not appear to be using it either.

Also why are you deleting the data structure you created after reading each item? If you want an array of diveInfo object you should create it, then iterate through it for each record you want to read. Within each record you will need to iterate through each score reading them individually.

This should get you in the right direction:

```
diveInfo theDiveInfo[40]; // This array of diveInfo will hold all of the information for 40 divers

for(int i = 0; i < NUM_RECORD; ++i)
{
  getline(inFile, theDiveInfo[i].diversName);

  for(int j = 0; j < NUM_SCORES; ++j)
    inFile >> theDiveInfo[i].scores[j];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using C++ like C. It would be easier, and clearer to create classes instead of structures.

You should create a class Parser which could handle your file and a class Person which could store the name, difficulty and an array of scores.

This way, your parser could create Person instances and it could store them in a container.

Also, you could use the STL to store your data.

Tell me if you need more explanations.

Regards,

Comment: Why don't you give an example of how to do that? It would make your answer a really helpful one.